# WP Site Hacked, Serp Google Spam

Tags: hacked

It all began when Google Ads suspended my ads because they found a malware in my WP site.
I tried to do scan with some free plugins: Wordefence, anti-malware and Securi, or online tool like: sitecheck.sucuri.net and transparencyreport.google.com, but I didn't find any malware though the SERP has been compromised!!there are about 100 fake url like these:

- `https://www.example.com/?lang=en&s=%2525E5%2525A4%2525A7%2525E5%2525A5%252596%2525E8%252580%252581%2525E8%252599%25258E%2525E6%25259C%2525BA%2525E7%2525BA%2525BF%2525E8%2525B7%2525AF%2525E6%2525A3%252580%2525E6%2525B5%25258B%252BQ82019309.com.com`
- `https://www.example.com/search/%e5%a4%a7%e5%a5%96%e8%80%81%e8%99%8e%e6%9c%ba%e8%af%9a%e4%bf%a1%e5%93%81%e7%89%8c+Q82019309.com.com/?lang=en/feed/rss2/`

I'm at my wit's end!! Is there someone that can help me?

Thanks

Comment: Stay calm. Start here: [FAQ My site was hacked](https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've cleaned up a few hacked sites, and have developed my own personal procedure [here](https://securitydawg.com/recovering-from-a-hacked-wordpress-site/).

But there are many googles on how to clean up. The basics are change the passwords of everything (hosting, database, FTP, users), reinstall WP and all themes/plugins from a known good source (WP repository), and manual inspection for bad files.

It's a bit of work, but I've been successful. The link in the comments is also a good place to start.

Comment: :( you know that external links and "go google" are not actually valid answers around here :(

Comment: Would you rather that I post the several hundred words in my post as the answer? My answer gave general guidelines, and agreed with the comment mentioning the other link. Rather than post the several hundred words, I posted a link. And also mentioned that there are additional resources available. I stand by my answer as valid and informative, and meeting guidelines: it agreed with the comment on the question, it provided basic information, and gave a link to detailed procedures (rather than posting the several hundred word procedure I have developed and used successfully).

Comment: if an answer to a question is likely to take 10 pages, then the question probably do not belong here in the first place (this question obviously do not belong), but at the very minimum there should be enough content in the answer to make it useful even if the external site dies. The general guidelines.... well it is so general it is almost useless. And regardless downvotes just indicate what someone thinks about the question/answer, maybe he just didn't got enough in the previous night, so no need to go defensive. OTOH I think that a moderator talked with you about the kind of questions

Comment: you answer and the quality of your answers. If this requires a discussion and further explanation why people see them as low quality you are welcome to discuss it in the "the loop" chat.

Comment: @RickHellewell thank you for the answer!! I find your article very interesting!! I will try to apply your sudgestions, I know that there isn't a specific solution for this kind of problem, I hope to solve the problem as soon as possible. Thanks

Comment: @SMadry Good luck with your efforts; it can be done (I've done it several times for clients, using my procedure.) Don't skip any steps. After cleanup/testing/verification, let the site sit for a few days while you monitor it. Then resubmit your sitemap to the googles to get the site re-indexed. Note that it will take some time (days) for the googles to finish reindexing. (And it is suggested here that if an answer matches your question [even if the question is not within the scope of this site, or others don't approve], please use the up arrow/checkmarks to indicate your approval. Thanks!